# c++ emitting inline functions

Tags: c++

Let's say that I have a library which contains a public definition of function `void foo();`. The library calls this function internally. To get the best performance I want internal calls to be inlined. I also want to prevent external code from seeing the definition so that later I can change the implementation without breaking the ABI. Here is a piece of code:

MyLib.h:

```
void foo();
```

MyLibInlined.h:

```
inline void foo() { code here }
```

MyLib.cpp

```
#define inline
#include "MyLibInlined.h"
```

The question is does it break the ODR or is it considered bad practice?

**EDIT:**
What if `foo` was a member function?

Comment: Primary issue is it wouldn't help much to force inlineing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If `foo` was a short function (for example a getter) and if it was called extensively internally then the performance would be much better.

Comment: Is this a C or a C++ question? The semantics of inline functions are different in the two, so please specify which one your question is about and remove the other tag.

Comment: Actually `foo` is a member function.

Comment: You can achieve better performance by profiling first.  Usually a design change will produce better performance (such as eliminating function calls).  Also, set the compiler optimizations accordingly, then profile again.   Generally, inlining is a micro-optimization and your performance bottlenecks lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

> The question is does it break the ODR or is it considered bad practice?

It doesn't break the ODR, but it breaks the rules in [dcl.fct.spec]:

> If a function with external linkage is
>   declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears;
>   no diagnostic is required.

Instead you should have a public version of the function, which is not declared inline, and have an internal version which you use inside your library:

```
// MyLibInlined.h
inline void foo_impl() { }
```

Then inside the library define `foo` as a call to the internal one:

```
// MyLib.cpp
#include "MyLibInlined.h"
void foo() { foo_impl(); }
```

Alternatively, if all the calls to `foo()` are in a single file you don't need to worry at all, just define it as a non-inline function, and let the compiler inline it in the file where the definition is visible:

```
// MyLib.h
void foo();

// MyLib.cpp
void foo() { code here }
// use foo ...
```

The `inline` keyword doesn't mean the function will be inlined, it means the definition is provided inline in headers. The compiler doesn't need that keyword to be able to inline it within the file where it's defined, because it can see the definition. You only need the `inline` keyword to allow the definition to appear in multiple translation units without causing a multiple definition error.

Comment: What if `foo` is a member function? Is there any better way than defining a wrapper class?

Comment: As the last part of my answer says, if you put all internal uses of the function into a single translation unit then there is no need to add the forwarding function or to declare anything `inline`. Make the body visible to all callers (by putting them in the same file as the definition of the body) and let the compiler decide when it's appropriate to inline it. It will probably do a better job of deciding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it does break the ODR, since inline is not so much a rule as it is a guideline. The compiler is allowed to not inline functions despite them being declared so.

On the other hand compilers are also allowed to inline functions that are not declared inline, and are likely to do so for small functions in internal calls (it can do so at link-time in some cases), so just don't worry about it.

Alternatively declare the inline version in a separate namespace and use inline namespaces to resolve it at compile-time (or using or whatever)(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Inline_namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be illegal based on this (C++14 3.2/6)

> There can be more than one definition of a [...] inline function with
>   external linkage [...] in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given
>   such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> [...]
>
> — each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens

Section 3.2 is the section on the one definition rule.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a cleaner variation on what you're doing:

```
// foo_pub.h -- public interface
#define foo()   foo_pub()
void foo_pub();

// foo_private.h -- internal used by library
#define foo()   foo_inline()
inline foo_inline() { ... }

// foo_pub.c -- definition for public function
void
foo_pub()
{
    foo_inline()
}
```